# Permanent rep point loss for bounty questions that never receive answers before bounty expires

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

Look at a question of mine here:

https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/i-cant-open-new-ie-tabs-on-my-wp7-5

I set a +50 bounty on this over a week ago.  The bounty expired, but I didn't get my bounty points back even though no one answered.  I set a new +100 bounty on it, but the same thing will probably happen again which will end up having me out by 150 points.  This is an especial hit for me on the windowsphone SE site in spite of the fact that I have pretty decent rep on stackoverflow and homeimprovement.

What is the reason for this non-refundable point policy?  If it's to keep people from spamming the same +50 bounty over and over again, isn't there another way to handle that other than permanent point loss?  Can you flag the question as previously having a bounty so the system knows to increase the next bounty while still allowing the user to afford bounties for other questions?

Answer (score 2):

Bounties are non-refundable; The idea being that they're a cost to the person offering the bounty to feature the question, and an incentive to those answering.

The system will auto-accept the bounty in certain circumstances, if the person offering the bounty doesn't accept before the time out.

Offering a higher bounty next time around may only benefit you if there are lots of featured questions, with higher bounties.